# Force HTTPS on homepage, but force HTTP on all others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force HTTPS on my homepage, but force HTTP on all others, via .htaccess. I have tried to follow numerous other solutions, with no luck.

My homepage should be formatted as: https://example.com

Other pages should be: http://example.com/page , http://example.com/page?var=asd , etc.

My attempt:

```
RewriteEngine On     

#Disable HTTPS for all pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Enable HTTPS for homepage
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

With both of those rules in place, the page doesn't load and I get a redirect error. With one of the rules commented out, the page loads, but isn't doing what I want. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On     

# Enable HTTPS for homepage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

# Disable HTTPS for all pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: That seems to be functional, however it is causing the login form on my site to not work, and while it adds HTTPS to the url, the browser says the certificate is invalid and your connection is not private. Forcing it with the rule RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] behaves correctly and the certificate loads as valid, but then all pages are loaded as HTTPS

Comment: ok try my updated rules now after clearing your browser cache.